# SUMPRODUCT marginal tax rate formula stops working when using Excel Table

Tags: excel

I followed this tutorial to calculate marginal tax rate in my Excel sheet: [Using SUMPRODUCT() to calculate variable rates and commissions](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/variablerate.html)

The magical formula is `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1>threshold), (A1-threshold), dRate)` where threshold, dRate are defined ranges. This has worked for me in the past before I converted the data range to an Excel Table, with structured references.

Now instead of `A1`, I use `[Income]` which is the column name in my table. And SUMPRODUCT has stopped working.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--([Income]>threshold), [Income]-threshold, dRate)`

It simply evaluates to #N/A. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jeeped it's not a secret it's just really really messy.... :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be reasonably assumed that the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) is in a column within your 'table' then you require the **@** symbol to reflect the relative row within the [Income] column.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--([@Income]>threshold), ([@Income]-threshold), dRate)
```

See [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-structured-references-in-Excel-table-formulas-75FB07D3-826A-449C-B76F-363057E3D16F) for more information.

[image: SUMPRODUCT in a Table]